# How to enable MSAA on editor

Tags: interface

I have 1680p display, which makes lines in Blender just horrible. How can I enable MSAA or any equivalent on the editor? I have a GTX 970. I already tried to enable it in Nvidia Control panel but it makes the UI blurry.

Comment: I think it should be using it by default... Try checking "full sample" under the anti-aliasing panel in the render settings to force Blender to use sampling on every RenderLayer. Also, can you post your .blend or a screenshot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable *Multisample* in *User preferences > System*:

[image]

Note that you might have to restart blender for the multisample setting to take effect.